# Internationalization in CakePHP JavaScript files

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

I'm wrapping up a project using Cakes internationalization features to allow our application to be translated into different languages. That's worked great.

A problem I've noticed though is there are a few places where text is added via JavaScript and this text does not currently come from the server at all. It's for things like dialogue boxes and a few pieces of text that change based on a users selection.

How have you handled this in your own applications? How would you handle this? Is there a library or component that handles this. What about any jQuery libraries?

Answer (score 8):

You can also do it using JavaScript translation files with this format:

```
lang = {
    no: "No",
    yes: "Ja",
    agreed: "Akkoord"
}
```

One file per language, for example: lang.nl.js, lang.es.js, lang.en.js...

Then, you can check the current language and, depending on it, load one or another file:

```
if($this->Session->read('Config.language') == 'es'){
    $this->Html->script('lang.es', array('inline' => false));
}else{ 
    $this->Html->script('lang.en', array('inline' => false));
}
```

And inside your javascripts, instead of using something like this:

```
alert("Yes");
```

You should use this:

```
alert(lang.yes);
```

And that's it :)

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a very common technique which works well.

Comment: I think this approach is way easier then the @thaJeztah (which is still good anyway). If you are using the jQuery Validator, for example, you can just expand the localized messages that the plugin already comes with.

Comment: Or even better $this->Html->script('lang.' . ($this->Session->read('Config.language'), array('inline' => false));

Answer (score 3):

CakePHP does not have a built-in / standard way of localizing *JavaScript*. It *does* offer various ways to localize strings 'in general'. See [Internationalization & Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html)

To localize strings that are output by JavaScript, consider;

1. For 'static' strings (i.e. strings that are not depending on the *content* of your website), create localization files for your scripts.
   Many plugins use this approach
   For example, see this page on localizing the JQuery-UI date picker [UI/Datepicker/Localization](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/Localization)
2. If you're already localizing strings in your website via .po files, and want to use the same translations in your JavaScript, you may consider to dynamically create the translation-files as mentioned in `1.)`, for example;

In your `app/Config/routes.php`, enable parsextensions, see [File Extensions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#file-extensions)

```
Router::parseExtensions('json');
```

Create a controller that will output strings localized as JavaScript/JSON

```
http://example.com/localized/strings/eng.json

class LocalizedController extends AppController {

    public function strings($lang)
    {
        if('json' !== $this->request->ext) {
            throw new NotFoundException();
        }

        // Switch to the requested language
        Configure::write('Config.language', $lang);

        $strings = array(
            'hello',
            'world',
        );

        //translated the strings
        $translations = array();
        foreach ($strings as $string) {
             $translations[$string] = __($string);
        }

        // build and send a JSON response
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $this->response->type('json');
        $this->response->body(json_encode($translations));
        return $this->response;
    }

}
```

This json file should now be accessible via `http://example.com/localized/strings/eng.json` and can be loaded from within your javascripts at runtime

#### note

Just to clarify; the example is *untested* and just to *illustrate* the idea of dynamically creating JSON (or JavaScript) files containing localized strings. The code is far from efficient and (at least part of) the code should **not** be inside the controller, but (for example) inside a model.

Answer (score 1):

For translating JavaScript inside my CakePHP applications, I use this library : https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.i18n , it's the one used in Wikipedia.

You have all the necessary files inside the src folder. It's quite easy to set up and use. Of course it works with any kind of application, not only CakePHP !

Comment: Does the `$ cake i18n extract` method support this of anykind or is this just toally unrelated to cake so just some library with no further benefits to be used in a cake project?

Comment: cake i18n extract is used to parse files inside your project for strings translated inside PHP with gettext(). The above library is used for translating strings inside JavaScript so has indeed no connection with CakePHP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution i'm using for cakePHP 3 :

in your layout file ( mine is default.ctp ) :

```
if( isset( $translated_js ) && !empty( $translated_js ) ){
    $this->Html->scriptStart($block_render);
    echo "var translated_js = " . json_encode( $translated_js ) . ";";
    $this->Html->scriptEnd();
}
```

Now in any controller add a beforeRender method :

```
public function beforeRender(Event  $event){
    parent::beforeRender( $event );     

    $translated_js = [
        'reinit_map' => __('Reinit map to default'),            
    ];

    $this->set( 'translated_js' , $translated_js );
}
```

This way you can use the gettext instructions.

In your JS files you can now use the translated eelements this way :

```
translated_js.reinit_map
```

Hope it helps someone searching a way to translate texts and pass to JS

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem like you and i found this link very helpful: http://jamnite.blogspot.de/2009/05/cakephp-form-validation-with-ajax-using.html

It's not up to date, but the main principle should be clear.

Comment: What would you call the manin principle here? Can you describe in one or two small sentences what the "should be clear" main principle *is* in your opinion and why you think it's important / of use?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this CakePHP plugin: https://github.com/wvdongen/CakePHP-I18nJs

It uses the functionality of Drupal 8 JavaScript translations. It has CakePHP console functions to generate .po file(s) (exactly as you're used with Cake), and to generate your translated .po files to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I use a more straightforward method. ( I do not know if it is the best, but it works ).

Inside the template file I define a series of hidden fields with the messages that js might need.

```
echo( $this->Form->hidden( 'msg-select-promotion-items', [ 'value' => __( 'Select promotion items' ) ] ) );
```

Here we take advantage of cake's own localization system.

And then in the js file :

```
alert( $('input[name=msg-select-promotion-items]').val() );
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.
Facundo.

Answer (score -1):

I took the easier path:

```
alert( "<?php echo __('This is my translated string'); ?>" )
```

This way you can keep all translations in a single place: the .po file